# css side vertical menu transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

Searched a lot but dint get specific answer. I am creating a website where i want to use a side bar.I want the side bar to expand to right on hover as shown below......Before  [image]

After

[image]

and the code

```css
.body {
 margin :0;
 border :0;
 
}
* {
 box-sizing : border-box;
}
.main-header {
 position : absolute ;
 width : 100% ;
 height : 44px;
 background-color : #999;
 z-index:4;
 
}

.main-content {
 padding-top :46px;
 
}

.side-nav {
 position : absolute;
 width:100% ;
 background-color:#666;
 height:100vh;
 z-index:3;
 padding-top:44px;
 
}

.side-nav ul {
 list-style :0;
 padding :0;
 margin:0;
}

.side-nav ul li {
 padding : 20px 10px;
 border-bottom :1px solid #333;
}
 
.side-nav ul li a {
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration : none;
 
}

.side-nav ul li a i {
 color: #333;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px)
{
 .side-nav {
 width :80px;
 }
 
 .side-nav ul li {
 text-align: center;
 }
 
 .side-nav ul li span:nth-child(2) {
 display:none;
 }
 
 .side-nav ul li i {
 font-size:  26px;
 }
 
 .main-content {
 
 margin-left:85px;
 }
 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px)
{
 
 .side-nav{
 width:200px;
 }
 .side-nav ul li {
 text-align :left;
 }
 .side-nav ul li span:nth-child(2) {
 display:inline;
 }
 
 .main-content {
 
 margin-left:205px;
 }
 
 
 
 
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="javascripts/jquery2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href="css/myCss.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="main-header">
<a href="#" class="nav-trigger"><span></span></a>
</div>

 <div class="side-nav">
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#"> <span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
      <span>xyz</span>
    </a></li>

    <li><a href="#"> <span><i class="fa fa-hourglass-2"></i></span>
      <span>sbc</span>

    </a></li>
    
    <li><a href="#"> <span><i class="fa fa-hourglass-2"></i></span>
      <span>Option 3</span>

    </a></li>
    
    <li><a href="#"> <span><i class="fa fa-hourglass-2"></i></span>
      <span>Option 4</span>

    </a></li>
    

   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>

 <div class="main-content">
  <p>asjjasjlasj</p>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

How do i do that using css and js with a nice transition .Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use transition only using **CSS3**, I apply it to width, but could be done to anything you think work better for you:

so just replace the lines below and it should works for you, if you don't want to apply to width, do it to any other attributes that work better for your case, so just replace .side-nav as below and add .side-nav:hover as well:

```
.side-nav {
    position : absolute;
    width:80px ;
    background-color:#666;
    height:100vh;
    z-index:3;
    padding-top:44px;
    -webkit-transition: width .5s; //add this line(Safari)
    transition: width .5s; //add this line(Safari)
}

//also add hover as below
.side-nav:hover {
    width:120px ; 
}
```

for more info about CSS transitions, look at the link below:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: You can add display :inline-bloc for the text if it's child or siblings on :hover, otherwise needs to use javascript or jquery to handle it for you

Comment: see this this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/8y494HN1ZdjJEyf1Os8h?p=preview..why the transition of the text alongside of the icon is smooth ..it looks shaky and not smooth...please increase the size of the output window and see

Comment: because you just do the transition to the width, if you think the font size needs that as well, do the same thing to the text as well... you will get a better and smoother transition that way

Answer (score 1):

It's actually pretty simple when you use [**CSS Transitions**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

First you can just use the `hover` selector to change the width:

```
.sidebar {
    width: 50px;
}

.sidebar:hover {
    width: 200px;
}
```

That technically already works but now **CSS Transitions** comes into play:

```
.sidebar {
    transition: width 300ms ease;
}
```

Basically what it does, whenever the `width` changes it plays a `300` millisecond long transition. `ease` is just an additional argument that makes the transition not so abrupt.

Everything together should look something like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/h7pbvsd2/)**

Comment: thanks :) upvoting your answer too as i cant accept two right answers